# Ignoring ' from javascript code, SQLite

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have a french category named `piqûres d'insectes` that I am pulling from a SQLite database. Unfortunately, the `'` in the category keeps breaking my javascript code, as seen in my pictures where it turns my breadcrumbs into undefined (half the word is missing as well clearly from the apostrophe). Is there a way I can pull this as just text so it does not break my code?

[image]

[image]

Javascript:

```
function txSuccessListAddSymptoms(tx,results) {
    //console.log("Read Additional Symptoms success");
    var category = getUrlVars().category;
    var mainsymptom = getUrlVars().mainsymptom;
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var addSymp;
    for (var i=0; i < len; i = i + 1) {
        addSymp = results.rows.item(i);

    };
    $('#addSymps').listview('refresh');
}
```

Comment: Would a text replace with /' be ideal?

Comment: Please react on my ander, thnx :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an escape character: `\'`

So for example try to use: `piqûres d\'insectes`

You can use the original name by adding this lines of code:

```
var str = getUrlVars().category;
var category = str.replace("'", "\'");
```

This code changes the `'` to `\'` if it is in the name.

I hope this helped for you

EDIT::

Soo.. this would be your script:

```
function txSuccessListAddSymptoms(tx,results) {
    //console.log("Read Additional Symptoms success");
    var str = getUrlVars().category;
    var category = str.replace("'", "\'");
    var mainsymptom = getUrlVars().mainsymptom;
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var addSymp;
    for (var i=0; i < len; i = i + 1) {
        addSymp = results.rows.item(i);

    };
    $('#addSymps').listview('refresh');
}
```